# Pycharm - Couldnt connect to console process

Tags: python, console, pycharm, mkstemp

I can't connect to the console process when I press Python console in **Tools**.

The interpeter tries to **"import mkdtemp, mkstemp"** but cant import **mkdtemp**

I have tried to check if there is something wrong with the project's settings but couldn't find something.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an issue with PyCharms configuration for your project. Try and delete `.idea` folder. This helped me when I had similar issues with PyCharm console.